# Issues with Java in-line comparator for sorting ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

```
List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();

Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator<String>()) {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
}
```

Right now I have a list of words and I want to sort them in ascending length. However, when I run the code above, I get syntax errors (e.g., the compiler says I have missing brackets and parentheses. However when I comment out the following:

```
Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
}
```

Everything runs fine. Am I implementing the sorting wrong?

Comment: You're missing the closing ")" and ";" on Collections.sort. On Java 8 you can do `(s1, s2) -> (s1.length() - s2.length())` instead of new Comparator...

Comment: Somehow I see a close vote coming up :P

Comment: @Adrian: Thanks for the catch! I replaced `new Comparator...` with `(s1, s2) -> (s1.length() - s2.length())` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're not using Java 8, are you?  8 and newer are the only ones that support that lambda syntax.

Comment: @KevinLin. Did any of the answers below help? If so please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. You may still accept an answer on a closed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler is telling you what's wrong. You have brackets in the wrong places.

Possibly you haven't realised that the `Comparator` you are creating is an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)? These are declared as: `new Comparator<String>() { ... }` so the bit you are treating as a statement block in the curly braces `{ ... }` goes *inside* the method argument section for the method invocation.

Your posted code:

```
Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator<String>()) {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
}
```

The corrected code:

```
Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
});
```

And if the changes are not obvious:

```
-       Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator()) {
+       Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.length() - s2.length();
            }
-       }
+       });
```